# How to scrape second <p> of webpage using python and Beautifulsoup

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I've been trying to work with BeautifulSoup because I want to try and scrape a webpage (https://www.imdb.com/search/title?release_date=2017&sort=num_votes,desc&page=1). So far I scraped some elements with success but now I wanted to scrape a movie description but I've been struggling. The description is simply situated like this in html :

```
<div class="lister-item mode-advanced"> 
    <div class="lister-item-content> 
       <p class="muted-text"> paragraph I don't need</p>
       <p class="muted-text"> paragraph I need</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to scrape the second paragraph which seemed easy to do but everything I tried gave me 'None' as output. I've been digging around to find an answer. In an other stackoverflow post I found that

```
find('p:nth-of-type(1)')
```

or

```
find_elements_by_css_selector('.lister-item-mode >p:nth-child(1)')
```

could do the trick but it still gives me

```
none #as output
```

Below you can find a piece of my code it's a bit low grade code because I'm just trying out stuff to learn

```
 import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from requests import get

url = 'http://www.imdb.com/search/title? 
release_date=2017&sort=num_votes,desc&page=1'
response = get(url)

html_soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
type(html_soup)
movie_containers = html_soup.find_all('div', class_='lister-item mode- 
advanced')

first_movie = movie_containers[0]

first_title = first_movie.h3.a.text
print first_title

first_year = first_movie.h3.find('span', class_='lister-item-year text-muted unbold')
first_year = first_year.text
print first_year

first_imdb = float(first_movie.strong.text)
print first_imdb

# !!!! problem zone ---------------------------------------------
first_description = first_movie.find('p', class_='muted-text')
#first_description = first_description.text
print first_description
```

the above code gives me this output:

```
$ python scrape.py
Logan
(2017)
8.1
None
```

I would like to learn the correct method of selecting html tags because it will be useful to know for future projects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> [find_all()](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find-all) method looks through a tag’s descendants and retrieves
>   all descendants that match your filters.

You can then use the list's index to get the element you need. Index starts at 0, so 1 will give the second item.

Change the first_description to this.

```
first_description = first_movie.find_all('p', {"class":"text-muted"})[1].text.strip()
```

Full code

```
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from requests import get

url = 'http://www.imdb.com/search/title?release_date=2017&sort=num_votes,desc&page=1'
response = get(url)

html_soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
type(html_soup)
movie_containers = html_soup.find_all('div', class_='lister-item mode-advanced')

first_movie = movie_containers[0]

first_title = first_movie.h3.a.text
print first_title

first_year = first_movie.h3.find('span', class_='lister-item-year text-muted unbold')
first_year = first_year.text
print first_year

first_imdb = float(first_movie.strong.text)
print first_imdb

# !!!! problem zone ---------------------------------------------
first_description = first_movie.find_all('p', {"class":"text-muted"})[1].text.strip()
#first_description = first_description.text
print first_description
```

Output

```
Logan
(2017)
8.1
In the near future, a weary Logan cares for an ailing Professor X. However, Logan's attempts to hide from the world and his legacy are upended when a young mutant arrives, pursued by dark forces.
```

Read the [Documentation](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) to learn the correct method of selecting html tags.

Also consider moving to python 3.

Comment: Thank you I tried to use find_all before but it didn't work because I used it wrong but this worked perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

Just playing around with `.next_sibling` was able to get it. There's probably a more elegant way though. At least might give you a start/some direction

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


html = '''<div class="lister-item mode-advanced"> 
    <div class="lister-item-content> 
       <p class="muted-text"> paragraph I don't need</p>
       <p class="muted-text"> paragraph I need</p>
    </div>
</div>'''


soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')


first_p = soup.find('div',{'class':'lister-item mode-advanced'}).text.strip()
second_p = soup.find('div',{'class':'lister-item mode-advanced'}).next_sibling.next_sibling.text.strip()



print (second_p)
```

**Output:**

```
print (second_p)
paragraph I need
```

Comment: I've tried your version but is it gives me AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'next_sibling'

Comment: sorry. I gave it shot. It works with the snip it example you gave, but there might be different situations within the whole html which returns None. You could also include it with `try:` and `except`. But honestly, the other solutions on here are probably better. Was just pointing out the `.next_sibling` function of beautifulsoup

Comment: thank you so much for helping. I try to work with all the answers because it's intresting to see all the possible ways to a solution. But your right I just needed to adjust it a litle.

Answer (score 0):

BeautifulSoup 4.71 support `:nth-child()` or any CSS4 selectors

```
first_description = soup.select_one('.lister-item-content p:nth-child(4)')
# or 
#first_description = soup.select_one('.lister-item-content p:nth-of-type(2)')

print(desc)
```

Comment: I tried the second option that you showed and it also worked! thank you  for your answer